# Returning the data type of a parameter

Tags: java

Is it possible to return the data type entered in Java.

For example

```
public a add(int a)
{
    return a + 10
}
```

Even though in this case only an `int` can be returned. How can you make it such that it returns the data type of what ever sent in?

Comment: elaborate more. what you want exactly ?

Comment: You make you pass the right data type.

Comment: I guess you could do it via overloading.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for something that Java doesn't offer (very easily)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "generics" are what you`re looking for. Like this:

```
public class MaximumTest
{
// determines the largest of three Comparable objects
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T x, T y, T z)
{                      
  T max = x; // assume x is initially the largest       
  if ( y.compareTo( max ) > 0 ){
     max = y; // y is the largest so far
  }
  if ( z.compareTo( max ) > 0 ){
     max = z; // z is the largest now                 
  }
  return max; // returns the largest object   
}

public static void main( String args[] )
{
  System.out.printf( "Max of %d, %d and %d is %d\n\n", 
               3, 4, 5, maximum( 3, 4, 5 ) );

  System.out.printf( "Maxm of %.1f,%.1f and %.1f is %.1f\n\n",
               6.6, 8.8, 7.7, maximum( 6.6, 8.8, 7.7 ) );

  System.out.printf( "Max of %s, %s and %s is %s\n","pear",
     "apple", "orange", maximum( "pear", "apple", "orange" ) );
}
}
```